# orgmode - summary table as different group from input table

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I need to summary a table according to one column and sum the specific rows of another column.

e.g. The summary table is generated from the input table. input table column 1 grouped to IN and OUT, column 2 is the sum of IN or OUT columns.

```
#+NAME: summary
| Item  | Value |
|-------+-------|
| IN    | $5.0  |
| OUT   | $7.0  |
| Total | $13.0 |

#+NAME: input
| Item | Value |
|------+-------|
| IN   | $1.5  |
| OUT  | $2.5  |
| IN   | $3.5  |
| OUT  | $4.5  |
|------+-------|

#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :results output :var input=input
(let (item (in 0)(out 0))
  (dolist (line input)
    (setq item (car line))
    (setq val (string-to-number (substring (cadr line) 1) 10))
    (if (string= item "OUT")
        (progn
          (setq out (+ out val))))
    (if (string= item "IN")
        (progn
          (setq in (+ in val)))))
  (print in)
  (print out)
  (print (+ in out))
)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 
: 5.0
: 
: 7.0
: 
: 12.0
```

Currently, I use elisp to calculate it but I know formula maybe better but I don't know how to do it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if two tables are necessary in your case. Some clean up to the data table or the "input" table is needed beforehand, by removing the `$` from the values which should be trivial by any editor.

I have two solutions for this, but I prefer the first one:

**Solution 1**

```
| Item  | USD   | Sum In | Sum Out |
|-------+-------+--------+---------|
| IN    |   1.5 |        |         |
| OUT   |   2.5 |        |         |
| IN    |   3.5 |        |         |
| OUT   |   4.5 |        |         |
|-------+-------+--------+---------|
| Total |  12.0 |    5.0 |     7.0 |
#+TBLFM: @2$2..@-1$2='(if (string= "$2" "[]") 0 $2);N    
#+TBLFM: @>$3='(apply '+ (org-lookup-all "IN" '(@2$1..@-1$1) '(@2..@-1$2) 'string=));L
#+TBLFM: @>$4='(apply '+ (org-lookup-all "OUT" '(@2$1..@-1$1) '(@2..@-1$2) 'string=));L
#+TBLFM: @>$2=$3+$4;f1
```

**P.S.**

- To apply the formulas, hit `C-c C-c` on each line starting with `TBLFM:`.
- The first `TBLFM` line is to convert any values with no data or with string to zeros before doing our calculations, otherwise error will be thrown.
- Have a look at this Worg [link](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-lookups.html) for more detail about using the lookup functions.

**Solution 2**

```
| Item  | Value | Sum In | Sum Out |
|-------+-------+--------+---------|
| IN    |   1.5 |    1.5 |       0 |
| OUT   |   2.5 |      0 |     2.5 |
| IN    |   3.5 |    3.5 |       0 |
| OUT   |   4.5 |      0 |     4.5 |
|-------+-------+--------+---------|
| Total |  12.0 |    5.0 |     7.0 |
#+TBLFM: @2$3..@-1$3='(if (string= "$1" "IN") $2 0);L::@>$3=vsum (@2..@-1);f1
#+TBLFM: @2$4..@-1$4='(if (string= "$1" "OUT") $2 0);L::@>$4=vsum (@2..@-1);f1
#+TBLFM: @6$2=$3+$4;f1
```

**P.S.**

- `@-1`: means the row before the last
- `;f1`: is just for output formatting, meaning 1 digit after the decimal place but you can change that to any thing.
- `;L` is used to interpolate lisp output to numbers after removing the quotations known of lisp
- `@>` means last row in the table, alternatively you can use `@6` but not extensible as the first notation, try adding more INs and OUTs, the table formula will still perform accordingly.
- `` `(lisp code);L `` is your friend to do lisp evaluation in table formulas.
- `TBLFM:` lines could be made one liner by separating them with `::`, I made it in three lines for better readability of code.
- Don't forget to hit `C-c C-c` while your point at the `TBLFM:` statement. Three times in this case, each for each line to apply the respective formulas and fill the values in the table.
- The third and fourth columns are calculated and are empty in the beginning. Only the first and second columns are assumed to be entered.
- Read Chapter 3 about Tables in the Org-manual for more detail.

Comment: Thanks, it works as expected. what's @2..@-1$2 mean? is it the same as @2$2..@-1$2?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly the same `@<row>$<column>`, but org-mode is smart enough to understand what you were trying to say and allows such shortcuts in writing references.

Answer (score 3):

Another version base on doctorate's answer but use remote table:

```
#+NAME: A
| Item  | Value |
|-------+-------|
| IN    |   5.0 |
| OUT   |   7.0 |
| Total |  12.0 |
#+TBLFM: @2$2='(apply '+ (org-lookup-all "IN" '(remote(B, @2$1..@>$1)) '(remote(B, @2$2..@>$2)) 'string=));L::@3$2='(apply '+ (org-lookup-all "OUT" '(remote(B, @2$1..@>$1)) '(remote(B, @2$2..@>$2)) 'string=));L::@4$2=vsum(@2$2..@-1$2);f1

#+NAME: B
| Item | Value | 
|------+-------+
| IN   |   1.5 | 
| OUT  |   2.5 | 
| IN   |   3.5 |
| OUT  |   4.5 |
```

Table name changed to A and B to save some characters in formula!

Answer (score 2):

Org mode with R is great, I modified the followings to sum up `Value` for each unique `Item` by `tapply()` and `sum()` function, thank for lucky1928's suggestion.
`addmargins()` function adds total "Sum" of each sum.

```
#+NAME: input
| Item | Value |
|------+-------|
| IN   | 1.5   |
| OUT  | 2.5   |
| IN   | 3.5   |
| OUT  | 4.5   |
| etc  |  10   |
| etc  |  20   |
|------+-------|


#+BEGIN_SRC R :session *R* :results output :exports both :var dd=input :colnames yes
addmargins(tapply(dd$Value,dd$Item,sum))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: etc  IN OUT Sum 
:  30   5   7  42
```

For HTML table export, just add `:results output value`.
We also transpose the result vector by `t()` function, for printing the table horizontally.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R :session *R* :results output value :exports both :var dd=input :colnames yes
t(addmargins(tapply(dd$Value,dd$Item,sum)))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| etc | IN | OUT | Sum |
|-----+----+-----+-----|
|  30 |  5 |   7 |  42 |
```

Comment: Amazing R solution. if I want to group all unique values from value and create a summary table, how to do it with R? I mean do not hardcode the key "IN" and "OUT" but extract it by R code!

Comment: @lucky1928 R code ```aggregate(dd$Value, by=list(Category=dd$Item), FUN=sum)```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you may try the `orgtbl-aggregate` package available on Melpa.

Input table

```
 #+NAME: input
 | Item | Value |
 |------+-------|
 | IN   |   1.5 |
 | OUT  |   2.5 |
 | IN   |   3.5 |
 | OUT  |   4.5 |
 |------+-------|
```

An aggregation using the `sum` function gathering `Value` with similar `Item`

```
 #+name: sums
 #+BEGIN: aggregate :table "input" :cols "Item sum(Value)"
 | Item | sum(Value) |
 |------+------------|
 | IN   |         5. |
 | OUT  |         7. |
 #+END:
```

An aggregation using the `sum` function gathering all `Value`

```
 #+BEGIN: aggregate :table "input" :cols "sum(Value)"
 | sum(Value) |
 |------------|
 |        12. |
 #+END:
```

Comment: I'm trying to get orgtbl-aggregate to work but keep getting the error "Invalid function: ((symbol-function(quote math-read-preprocess-string)) (function identity)). Any idea what's wrong?